# Vertical navigation menu (left side of page) using Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I am trying to create a vertical navigation menu at the left side of a web page using ExtJS. I inspire the sample dashboard at http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/. Even googling didn't provide any sample code. If anyone can help with a sample code, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

For the example, it looks like they were using the tab panel to achieve this function.

Inside the tab panel add two configs tabPosition: 'left' and tabRotation: 0, then you will have the left side tabs. And then you can either use cls or ui configs to apply the style.

Also Ext JS Kitchen Sink has the examples. Check the link below: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#side-navigation-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Back then, I did it as follows:

If you look into the HTML source code ("inspect element"), you see that the left-hand part HTML starts

```
<div class="x-treelist ...
```

which points you towards [`xtype:'treelist'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.list.Tree.html) (just like `x-panel` is for `xtype:'panel'` and `x-container` is for `xtype:'container'`).

The docs should then provide you with everything you need to know about the general usage; for details about how sencha did it in this special case, you can enter in your browser console:

```
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query("treelist")[0]);
```

At least Chrome will return you the component, where you can navigate through all properties to see e.g. what configs they used etc.

For the relevant CSS you can navigate the DOM tree and copy the relevant CSS information into your project from the CSS tab, e.g.

```
.x-treelist-navigation {
    background-color: #32404e;
    background-position-x: 44px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
...
```